# c# MySqlCommand doesn't appear to be resolving Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to run a MySqlCommand with a parameter, but when I look in the SQL logs, the parameter is showing up.

I've tried with both @ and ?, tried with 'old syntax=yes' in my sqlconnection string also.

Here's my code.

```
bool CheckLoginDetails(string username, string password){
    DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("select * from `accounts` where `username` = '@username';", SL.Database.connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@username", username);
    dt.Load (command.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Here's the SQL logs.

```
150823  3:19:50    22 Connect   root@localhost on unity_test
       22 Query SHOW VARIABLES
       22 Query SHOW COLLATION
       22 Query SET character_set_results=NULL
       22 Init DB   unity_test
150823  3:19:52    22 Query select * from `accounts` where `username` = '@username'
```

I'm using .net 2.0 and I'm unsure of the mysql dll version, I found that here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/reading-database-and-or-spreadsheets.11466/

I'm unable to upgrade .net due to Unity. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion (not tested):

```
bool CheckLoginDetails(string username, string password){
    string sql = select * from accounts where username = ?";
    MySqlCommand command  = new MySqlCommand(sql);
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("", username));
    MySqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
    ...
}
```

The main point is that "?" should work.

Comment: This one worked, thanks a lot! New code is like so, for anyone wondering.

`MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("select * from accounts where username = ?username", SL.Database.connection);
  command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("username", username))`

Answer (score 0):

Try    command.Parameters.Add("@username", MysqlDbType.Varchar).Value = username;

Should work !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("select * from `accounts` where `username` = '@username';", SL.Database.connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@username", username);
```

to

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("select * from accounts where username = @username;", SL.Database.connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@username", username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(suggestion)

```
bool CheckLoginDetails(string username, string password){
DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("select * from accounts where username = @username;", SL.Database.connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@username", username);
dt.Load (command.ExecuteReader());
```

}